# difference between drain and release

Tags: memory-management

i want to know the difference between drain and release in memory management..please help me with suitable example.

Comment: Need more context to understand your question.

Comment: release means object count will be decreased by one ... what drain will do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a garbage collected environment,
>   **release** is a no-op. NSAutoreleasePool
>   therefore provides a **drain** method that
>   in a reference-counted environment
>   behaves the same as calling **release**,
>   but which in a garbage collected
>   environment triggers garbage
>   collection (if the memory allocated
>   since the last collection is greater
>   than the current threshold).
>   Typically, therefore, you should use
>   **drain** rather than **release** to dispose
>   of an autorelease pool.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: ok.. thank u.                                          NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
 some code
[pool release];
so i have to use [pool drain] instead of [pool release]...right...?

Comment: @Madhumitha You don't have to thank me. Just upvote or accept the answer. That is the currency of SO.